# asp:CheckBox not fire BeginRequest like asp:Button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                var elem = args.get_postBackElement();
                ActivateAlertDiv('visible', 'AlertDiv', elem.value + ' processing...');
            }
            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                ActivateAlertDiv('hidden', 'AlertDiv', '');
            }
            function ActivateAlertDiv(visstring, elem, msg) {
                var adiv = $get(elem);
                adiv.style.visibility = visstring;
                adiv.innerHTML = msg;
            }
        </script>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="Server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" GroupingText="Update Panel">
                    Last update:
                    <%= DateTime.Now.ToString()%>.
                    <br />
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Checkbox1" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Process 1" OnClick="ProcessClick_Handler" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="Process 2" OnClick="ProcessClick_Handler" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div id="AlertDiv" class="AlertStyle">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Button1 and Button2 fired the beginRequest event but Checkbox1 didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the AutoPostback to true in the checkbox:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Checkbox1"  AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to to set AutoPostBack property of CheckBox to True

Answer (score 0):

Add `AutoPostBack="true"` and add event      `oncheckedchanged="Checkbox1_CheckedChanged1"`

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Checkbox1" AutoPostBack="true"
 oncheckedchanged="Checkbox1_CheckedChanged1"/>
```